# create an image and dialog box on same screen in php

Tags: php, html, image, dialog

I'm trying to create an image and a dialog box together on one screen in php. I eventually want the dialog box to be able to control the image (such as showing more lines on the image). When I run the code it only shows the image, not the dialog box. I must be missing some extra code to make it work. Please help. Thankyou for any suggestions.

```php
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $png_image = imagecreate(50, 50); 
    imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);
    imageline($png_image, 0, 0, 50, 50, $black);  
    imagepng($png_image);
    imagedestroy($png_image);   
?>

<html>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create anything on screen in php. It only generates files. You can have a php script to generate an image. Let's call it *img.php*:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $png_image = imagecreate(50, 50); 
    imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);
    imageline($png_image, 0, 0, 50, 50, $black);  
    imagepng($png_image);
    imagedestroy($png_image);   
?>
```

And you can have another `.html` or `.php` file which generates html-code to include that image:

```
<html>
  This is the image:
  <img src="img.php">
</html>
```

if you want to recreate image depend on user actions, you have to include some JavaScript into the html code, which will force image to reload.

Comment: That worked @AterLux, I made two different files in the same folder and the program ran correctly, I'll research more about the JavaScript that recreates depending on user actions.